# What is the normal Facebook API response time?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, httpresponse

My app is currently on beta testing, so a few people are actually using my app to connect to Facebook through either WiFi, 3G, or EDGE.

However they are reporting that it's very slow. I checked out my API response time, and it turns out that it's `31,546ms`. How can it be so long? That means that users of my app has to wait about half a minute before they can post their stuff successfully to Facebook... Anyone has any idea how to speed it up?

P.S. I checked this out from going to the inisights of my app.

Comment: i had same issue a few months ago, it turns out my dns settings for the cloud i had set up was not configured correctly.  "ipv6 errors."  The issue stemed to alot of users, example Godaddy.com hosting, had to update all of their dns servers.